# Input directive with ng-message validation

Tags: angularjs

I would like to know if something like this is possible in angular

```
<form name='form'>
  <input-directive-with-ngmessages1 ... inputname='field1' form='form' />
  <input-directive-with-ngmessages2 ... inputname='field2' form='form' />
</form>
```

I know that validation system in angular is working based on form name, but I would like to make components from inputs, move ng-messages inside custom input directives, passing just form name to it, with possiblity to get overall form validation status,

I was looking about dynamic forms/validation on stackoverflow, but I didn't find something like above example, thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely doable. My suggestion: Require an `ngModel` to make a custom control (as described [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)) use transclusion for the messages. Sample code:

```
app.directive('inputDirectiveWithNgmessages', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template:
            '<input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.model" name="ctrl.inputname" />' + 
            '<div ng-messages="ctrl.$error" role="alert" ng-transclude>' +
                // element content, i.e. the messages will be transcluded here
            '</div>',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        require: ['ngModel', 'inputDirectiveWithNgmessages'],
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrls) {
            var ngModel = ctrls[0];
            var inputDirectiveWithNgmessages = ctrls[1];
            inputDirectiveWithNgmessages.inputname = attrs.inputname;
            inputDirectiveWithNgmessages.setModel(ngModel);
        },
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        controller: function($scope) {
            var self = this;

            this.model = null;

            this.setModel = function(ngModel) {
                this.$error = ngModel.$error;

                ngModel.$render = function() {
                    self.model = ngModel.$viewValue;
                };

                $scope.$watch('ctrl.model', function(newval) {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(newval);
                });
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Usage is quite simple - place the messages inside the element:

```
<input-directive-with-ngmessages ng-model="model1" inputname="field1" ng-required="true">
    <div ng-message="required">Required field</div>
</input-directive-with-ngmessages>
```

No need to specify the form name.

And a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/12sf82p3/

**THE CATCH**: Standard validators we have been comfortably using with inputs, e.g. `ng-pattern`, do NOT work out of the box in this (except for the `ng-required`). You see `ng-pattern` is not a directive; it is handled as an attribute by Angular's standard input directive. The workaround is to implement the validators you want as directives and place them on the `<input-directive-with-ngmessages>`, e.g.:

```
<input-directive-with-ngmessages ng-model="..." inputname="..." my-pattern="[A-Z][0-9]">
```

The `my-pattern` directive will use the standard `$validators` pipeline of `ngModel` to implement regular expression validation.

A benefit of this is that the template of the directive can be tweaked to suit any needs. E.g. it could create form element markup for Twitter's Bootstrap.

Finally you may want to take a look at [egkyron](https://github.com/nikospara/egkyron) for an alternative to form validation, i.e. model based validation.

Comment: I thought rather about something like this one: http://plnkr.co/edit/W1KxuL?p=preview

Comment: This contains lots of unnecessarily repeated code: check the difference between `inputName.js`, `inputAge.js`, `inputEmail.js` and `input-age.html`, `input-name.html`, `input-email.html`. It will not scale well for many inputs.